# Trying to bin data in Pandas, but always stops after certain row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of float variables, and I would like to bin them into groups that I will eventually generate binary columns for. Right now I have a function

```
def getBins(column)
```

that returns a list of float bounds (this seems to work perfectly fine)

In the main I call

```
bounds = getBins(dataframeMini[col])
```

From there I want to overwrite the column with the binned version. I've tried two different ways of doing this and have run into nearly the same problem each time. For the first, I tried using Pandas.cut

```
thing = pd.cut(pd.Series(dataframeMini[col].astype(float)),bins=bounds,include_lowest=True)
dataframeMini[col].update(pd.Series(thing))
```

In all cases of different columns with different data, the column only changes up until row 376 and stops. I was not sure if this was a problem with the Categorical variable it kept returning, so I tried to do it manually.

```
array = []
for item in dataframeMini[col]:
   for i in range(1,len(bounds)):
       if float(item) >= float(bounds[i-1]) and float(item) < float(bounds[i]):
           array.append(i+1)
       elif float(item) < float(bounds[0]):
           array.append(1)
       elif float(item) >= float(bounds[len(bounds)-1]):
           array.append(len(bounds))
dataframeMini[col].update(pd.Series(array))
```

This also did not overwrite the whole way, even though when I printed out the length of the array, there were exactly the same number of items as there were rows to overwrite! Would anyone happen to know what is going on?

Comment: Since `update()` aligns on index, can you guarantee that `dataframeMini` has index `np.arange(len(dataframeMini))`?

Comment: They should be. the manual array had 2136 items in it but also stops after item 376 which is not a factor of 2136. Also, wouldn't the Series and a regular array both index 0 through n anyway?

Comment: The array and Series you created above will have the index [0..N), yes. But does your `dataframeMini` have this index?

Comment: Don't dataframes also index from 0 to N?

Comment: Sometimes. If you query a DataFrame and remove some rows in the middle during the query, then it definitely *won't* have that index range. The only way to know for sure is to look at `dataframeMini.index` and manually verify.

Comment: Thank you thank you!!! That was exactly it! The dataframe I was using was a subset of rows from a larger one. Once I called reset_index(drop = True) it fixed the whole problem.

Comment: Alright, I've posted my response as an answer. Please "accept" it by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't how you made the array; the problem is that `update()` aligns on index. So if you've done anything to your DataFrame so that its index isn't `np.arange(len(dataframeMini))`, then `update()` will fail.

A better idea is to just assign the array directly to your column:

```
dataframeMini[col] = array
```

Because they are the same length, the original values will be overwritten regardless of index.